# Existe ambiente para desenvolvimento Nodejs cloud?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estudo em uma faculdade que ainda não homologou o nodejs nos equipamentos. Contudo, onde posso encontrar um ambiente cloud para desenvolver minhas aplicações nodejs e expression ?

Comment: O Google oferta o serviço pago de desenvolvimento para Node.js através do Google Cloud Platform. Já conhece a ferramenta?
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/

Comment: Não. Mim indicaram o heroku.com para desenvolvimento... porém estou achando a curva de aprendizado...longa!

Comment: Você quer desenvolver em cloud ou hospedar sua aplicação? Por que Heroku é para hospedagem, e é muito simples. No envio, ele apenas lê o package.json e faz o resto.

Comment: Quero desenvolver em cloud  visto que os computadores da universidade não permitem configurar o ambiente para nodejs.